# Symfony and API Platform - retrieving data by slug or userToken or any other field different than ID

Tags: php, api, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

What I'm trying to do is:

- send a request from my frontend to API custom url to activate user account (/account/activate/someTokenValue)
- retrieve user form database by confirmationToken value
- activate user account and save it to database
- return activation information (or some errors if e.g. token is invalid)

So I've defined:

```
* @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "get",
 *     "activate_account"={
 *         "method"="get",
 *         "path"="/account/activate/{confirmationToken}",
 *         "controller"=UserActivate::class
 *     }
 * })
 */
```

In my `User` entity class there is `UserActivate` controller and `UserActivateHandler` that is invoked by `UserActivate` controller. 
I've set `ApiProperty` `identifier` for ID to `false` and for `confirmationToken` to `true`.

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     *
     */
    private $id;

    /**
      * 
      * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
      * @ApiProperty(identifier=true)
      */
    protected $confirmationToken;
```

However API Platform still requires an ID and it doesn't seem to see `confirmationToken` parameter.

Basically my question is, how I can retrieve an object by, in this case, `confirmationToken`?

Comment: What you could do is disable automatic retrieval of the entity and then fetch it yourself, using the token. See: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#entity-retrieval. Another option for retrieving the entity by the token when calling your custom operation could be to create a custom EntityDataProvider for your action. See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/

Comment: You use the `ApiProperty` in correct way. It should work as intended. Eventually it can help to clear the cache (`bin/console cache:clear`), to restart the server and/or in case of changes in the entities to generate and run new migration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, getting an entity by a different property than the one indicated as the identifier; you did well with the property annotations:

```
@ApiProperty(identifier=false) 
@ApiProperty(identifier=true)
```

but at the same time you have to mantain the {id} in your path, so change

```
"path"="/account/activate/{confirmationToken}",
```

to

```
"path"="/account/activate/{id}"
```